# Using Adwords, is it possible to create url specific to each keyword for thousands of keywords?

Tags: google-ads-api

Every URL ends with the same pattern, "Part-123456789" where the "Part" is a constant and the "123456789" is a part number. I want to run an adwords campaign targetting every part # and directing to the unique url for that part. Is there a simple way to do this?

Note: Adwords Editor is giving me ambiguous rowtype errors whenever I try to upload the keywords and URL's together in the same line of a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The available value track parameters for AdWords tracking templates offers both the keyword ID and matched keyword:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en

You could use this to determine the part number in the URL but it may require some mapping in the content management system.